# unmute video JS script working in console but not page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following video on a website

```
   <video class="c-banner-video__media" muted="" autoplay="" playsinline="" loop="" poster="https://foredigital.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/BANNER-1-FIRST-FRAME.png">
      <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.hd.mp4?s=20b86d3926f13e5fbfe3cade6c0f4f74c5454d54&amp;profile_id=175" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 1280px)">
      <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.hd.mp4?s=20b86d3926f13e5fbfe3cade6c0f4f74c5454d54&amp;profile_id=174" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 960px)">
      <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.sd.mp4?s=2b9adcfe5fecdfe3b2d1f79e966b74cb36d628f3&amp;profile_id=165" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 640px)">
      <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.sd.mp4?s=2b9adcfe5fecdfe3b2d1f79e966b74cb36d628f3&amp;profile_id=164" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
```

The following JS works in console but not in on a local copy or live site

```
  <script>

     var video = document.querySelector(".c-banner-video__media");

     video.muted = false;

  </script>
```

I am confused as to why this is, does it need to be wrapped in a document.ready function?

Currently it just stops the autoplay of the video completely and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you put your script at the end of `body`?

Comment: if the script load before the video object .. then it will not work because there is no object return on query selector .

Comment: The script is loaded at the end of the body yes

Comment: How many elements with the class `c-banner-video__media` do you have? Are you defining the variable `video` only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the code on the [playing event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/playing):

> The playing event is fired when playback is ready to start after having been paused or delayed due to lack of data.

```js
document.querySelector(".c-banner-video__media").addEventListener('playing', function(e) {
    this.muted = false;
})
```

```html
<video class="c-banner-video__media" muted="" autoplay="" playsinline="" loop="" poster="https://foredigital.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/BANNER-1-FIRST-FRAME.png">
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.hd.mp4?s=20b86d3926f13e5fbfe3cade6c0f4f74c5454d54&amp;profile_id=175" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 1280px)">
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.hd.mp4?s=20b86d3926f13e5fbfe3cade6c0f4f74c5454d54&amp;profile_id=174" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 960px)">
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.sd.mp4?s=2b9adcfe5fecdfe3b2d1f79e966b74cb36d628f3&amp;profile_id=165" type="video/mp4" media="all and (min-width: 640px)">
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/278635957.sd.mp4?s=2b9adcfe5fecdfe3b2d1f79e966b74cb36d628f3&amp;profile_id=164" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code, specifically the **muted** attribute is misspelled. With this type of attributes in which there is no need to specify any value, there are two ways to write it out:

1-

```
<video muted></video>
```

2-

```
<video muted="muted"></video>
```

But never write **muted=""**

Try to change with what I have said, I hope it is helpful. :)